# Grabbing a control from an ascx page in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have an .ascx user control that is in my search.aspx page. How do I grab a control from the .ascx user control in the search.aspx.cs code behind ?

```
keywordSearch.Value = "value"; 
// the code behind can't see the keywordSearch control
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally inner controls are not exposed from templated user controls, because they're declared as  `protected`. You can however expose the control in a public property, like this:

```
public TextBox CustomerName {
    get { return txt_CustomerName; }
}
```

Edit: If you need to *set* the value of the control then you're better off with a property that exposes the value, not the control:

```
public string CustomerName {
    get { return txt_CustomerName.Text; }
    set { txt_CustomerName.Text = value; }
}
```

Comment: how would you write a setter too?

Comment: If you need to _set_ the value as well then you should expose a property as a string or other type depending on the control in question here, and then get/set the value in the accessor. You want to expose a getter for the value of a control but not a setter for the control itself.

Answer (score 3):

You might be able to provide a public (or internal) property in your user control's code behind that allows "getting" the control in the user control.  You could then access that property from your page's code behind.

Answer (score 1):

Try FindControl method to access a control at container page :

```
((TextBox)Page.FindControl("keywordSearch")).Value = "value";
```